# Recall an Intent in Android

Tags: android, performance, android-intent

How do i recall an Intent in Android Studio?
I am trying to build a service which uses an intent. In some case, I am trying to send a broadcast up to a specific number of times( let's say X times) if intent is not received by the activity. After  X times, still activity does not get the intent , i want to delete that intent and do some other operation for that activity.

Answer (score 0):

As a way to implement this, you can broadcast [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) events through [JobQueue](https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue) job, that can retry sending of an event for needed number of times. The subscriber activity subscribed to this event, and creates your Intent only in case if event was handled.

From code perspective this could be implemented as:

Event, that will be broadcasted:

```
class SomeEvent(val isSuccess: Boolean)
```

Job class, which instance is initiated by your service:

```
class SendCustomEventJob() : Job{

    @Inject
    @Transient
    lateinit var eventBus: EventBus

    // dagger jobs component injection
    override fun inject(appComponent: AppComponent) {
        super.inject(appComponent)
        appComponent.inject(this)
    }

    override fun onRun() {
        // some logic goes here, like API calls
        eventBus.post(SomeEvent(true))
    }

    override fun shouldReRunOnThrowable(throwable: Throwable, runCount: Int, maxRunCount: Int): RetryConstraint {
        if(runCount == 3)
            // your custom job exceptions handling logic
    }

    override fun getRetryLimit(): Int = 3 // your custom retries number
    override fun onAdded() { }

    override fun onCancel(cancelReason: Int, throwable: Throwable?) {
        eventBus.post(SomeEvent(false))
    }
}
```

And handling of events in your activity-subscriber:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
fun onFetchedCustomEvent(event: SomeEvent) {
    if (!event.isSuccess)
        return

    //create your intent here...
}
```